# Two way databindning in android

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin, android-databinding, two-way-binding

lets say I have a login form that await until the user imports a 10 digit phone number, then it changes the next's button visibility
How can I achieve that in XML with no code?
here is the phone check function:

```
fun EditText.isValidPhone() = this.text.length == 10
```

and layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phoneEdit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:hint="@string/mobile_phone"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="10"
        android:textColor="@color/regular_text"
        android:textColorHint="@color/hint"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/authorization_next"
        style="@style/accept_button"
        android:text="@string/next"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you using the Android Data Binding Library or any other facilities?

Comment: Android data binding from google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generated data binding *Java* class does not know about extension methods, so you have to import the appropriate class holding the static extension methods. Assuming the file name is *extensions.kt*, this class name would be `ExtensionsKt` Also you have to import `View` into your binding. The you can use the `onTextChanged` attribute to define a callback and conditions for the text change.

```
android:onTextChanged="@{(text, start, before, count) -> authorizationNext.setVisibility(ExtensionsKt.isValidPhone(phoneEdit) ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE)}" />
```

Maybe it would be useful to just define an extension for `CharSequence` instead

```
fun CharSequence.isValidPhone() = length == 10
```

and use it as `ExtensionsKt.isValidPhone(text)` instead.